# How to Find if an Array Includes a Specific Array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, include

I have a two dimensional array in a Javascript programme. Example:

```
let Array = [["Green", "Red"], ["Flower", "Daisy"], ["North", "West"]]
```

I want to be able to run a ".includes" test on it to find a specific array in the array.
Example:

```
if (Array.includes(["Green", "Red"]) === true) {More code} else {Else code}
```

This however does not work, the array is not detected and the programme moves on into "Else code". Is there away to detect specific arrays in an array without using a for loop to individually go though each array?

Comment: You are overriding javascript Array object!  Chose a different name, like: array.

Comment: If you don't mind iterating over the array, then you can use `JSON.stringify` to compare items in array with test array: 
`var testArrayStringified=JSON.stringify(testArray);
var included=false;
for(var i=0; i<array.length && !included; i++) 
  included=JSON.stringify(array[i])==testArrayStringified);
included?{More code}:{Else code};`

Comment: Thank you but I cannot get it to work, your syntax appears to be wrong? I do not want to particular use iteration as there are several two dimensional areas in a third array and I am already using iteration to go through each one of them to check if they have the 3rd level array.

Comment: Never mind I solved it like this: let Array2 = [["Green", "Red"], ["Flower", "Daisy"], ["North", "West"]]
    if (JSON.stringify(Array2).includes(JSON.stringify(["Green", "Red"])) === true) {
      console.log("Yes it includes it")
    } else {
      console.log("No it does not include it")
    }

Comment: Fixed it: `array=[["Green", "Red"], ["Flower", "Daisy"], ["North", "West"]];
testArray=["Green", "Red"];
var testArrayStringified=JSON.stringify(testArray);
var included=false;
for(var i=0; i<array.length && !included; i++)    included=JSON.stringify(array[i])==testArrayStringified;
if(included) {console.log("Included")}
else {console.log("Not Included")};`

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work:

```
let Array2 = [["Green", "Red"], ["Flower", "Daisy"], ["North", "West"]]
if (JSON.stringify(Array2).includes(JSON.stringify(["Green", "Red"])) === true) {
  console.log("Yes it includes it")
} else {
  console.log("No it does not include it")
}
```